# Basic Complex variable question.

Tags: complex-numbers

An assignment was given and it seems easy . . . yet confusing. So I am here with this problem:

> Use $-1=(-1,0)$ and $z=(x,y)$ to show that $(-1)z=-z$.

I can see that $(-1)z=-z$ is equivalent to $(-1)(x,y)= -(x,y)$.  But how do I use $-1=(-1,0)$ and $z=(x,y)$ to show that $(-1)z=-z$?

I have $-1$ is $(-1,0)$ and $z$ is $(x,y)$, and if I multiply these two then I would get $(x,0)$, which cannot be $-z$. Any help would be appreciated.

$$(1,0)(x,y)=(x,0)$$

Comment: Did you mean $-1=(-1,0)$?

Comment: yes. sorry.i meant -1=(-1,0)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing what the question is supposed to say is that $-1=(-1, 0)$.  In general, a complex number $z$ can be written as $x+yi$, for some real numbers $x$ and $y$, or, equivalently, as $(x,y)$. Therefore, you could write $(-1)z$ as the product $(-1 + 0i)(x + yi)$.  You would multiply these two terms just as you would any two binomials, keeping in mind the fact that $i^2=-1$.

Comment: you're right. i meant to say -1=(-1,0)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some mistakes. This looks like Rudin's (and others') definition for complex number arithmetic. The definition of the product of two complex numbers should be

$$(x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2) = (x_1x_2-y_1y_2,x_1y_2+x_2y_1).$$

Additionally, we should have $-1 = (-1,0)$ not $(1,0)$. Does this help?